# MATLAB difference between numerical integration functions

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I need to integrate an expression using MATLAB. What is the difference between these functions?

`QUAD`, `QUAD8`, `QUADL`, `DBLQUAD`

Comment: What did the documentation say? Perhaps we can help you understand that?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the material provided form the [Matlab site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/index.html) you'll see these explanations:

[quad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html):

> Numerically evaluate integral, adaptive Simpson quadrature

[quadl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quadl.html):

> Numerically evaluate integral, adaptive Lobatto quadrature

[dblquad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dblquad.html):

> Numerically evaluate double integral over rectangle

I didn't look for quad8 as it wasn't readily available, but I'm sure that you'll be able to find it from here.  Also each of the link provide a greater detail as to how they work exactly.